# swift: modified position will change when keyboard shows

Tags: swift, keyboard, position

when I change the position of a UITextField and open the keyboard the UITextField jumps back to the original position.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.TextField.center.y     = self.view.frame.height / 2
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if(ifnew == true) {
            self.feld.center.y  = self.view.frame.height / 2
        }
    }
```

I the solution